# Prevent \n from getting rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, special-characters

```js
var i = 'Hello \n World'
console.log(i)   

/*
Output:
Hello
World
*/

/*
Desired output: Hello \n world
*/

var j = 'javscr\u0012ipt'
console.log(j)

/*
Output:
javscr ipt
*/

/*
Desired output: javscr\u0012ipt
*/
```

Above code shows what output I am supposed to get when i have a special character in the string, what output I want. I don't want the special character whether it is **line break** or **unicode** to get **rendered on screen** and rather they should be a **part of string**. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this. Any help will be appreciated ( I am using angularjs as framework) .

Comment: You can just add another forward slash \ to escape the default \n , so console.log("Hello \\n World") will give you your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can transform your string as json one to display special character

```js
var i = 'Hello \n World'
console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
var j = 'javscr\u0012ipt'
console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
```